# Outlook 2000 sorts contacts by first name

Tags: microsoft-outlook

A friend of mine has an Outlook 2000 and has a problem with the sorting of the contacts. Within the contact-book everything's right, but if you write a new email and press the To-Button, the contacts are sorted by their first name instead of the last name. How to change that?

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, its for 03/07:

http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/et_sort_address.htm

```
* In Outlook 2007:
      o Select Tools | Account Settings... from the menu.
      o Go to the Address Books tab. 
* In Outlook 2003:
      o Select Tools | E-mail Accounts... from the menu in Outlook.
      o Make sure View or change existing directories or address books is selected.
      o Click Next >. 
* Highlight the desired address book.
* Click Change....
* Select the desired sort order (First Last or File As) under Show names by.
* Click Close.
* Click Finish
```

Don't have a copy of 2k to test with, but can't be that different.

Comment: That got me on the right track it's actually: `Tools -> Address Book -> View -> Sort by`. Thank you!